# ¿Porque se repite funcion each() jquery?

Tags: jquery, datatables, aplicación-web, each

estoy trabajando con el plugin datatables de jquery,muestros 4 tablas de las cuales 1 es la Padre y 3 hijos, lo que hago es que al seleccionar un registro de la tabla Padre me muetre registros en la tablas Hijos, esa parte funciona bien , los que pasa es que quiero hacer una validación que cuando el registro de la tabla hijo tenga varios null me bloquee/des un boton que esta afuera de la tabla, aqui tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
tablaUsuarios.on('select',function()
{    
   tablaCursos.ajax.reload(function(){ //esta parte se repite
        var arrData=[];

        $("#tablaCursos tr").each(function(tbody,table){
            var currentRow=$(this);

            var col1_valueC = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();
            var col2_valueC = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
            var col3_valueC = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text();

            var obj={};
            obj.categoria = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();
            obj.tipCurso  = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
            obj.curso     = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text();

            arrDataC = obj;
            console.log(arrDataC); //me devuelve 3 salidad cuando deberia ser una por cada vez que selecciona la tabla padre

        });
  
        if(arrDataC['categoria'] == '' & arrDataC['tipCurso'] == '' & arrDataC['curso'] == ''){
             $('#btnAddCurso').attr("disabled",true);
             console.log('LIMPIO BLOQUEADO');
         }else{
             $('#btnAddCurso').attr("disabled",false);
             console.log('SUCIO DESBLOQUEADO');
         }
         console.log('Sali');
    });

});
tablaUsuarios.on('deselect',function(){
    tablaprueba.ajax.reload();
    $('#btnAddEstudio').attr("disabled",true);

    tablaCursos.ajax.reload();
    $('#btnAddCurso').attr("disabled",true);

    tablaExpExt.ajax.reload();
    $('#btnAddExpExt').attr("disabled",true);

});
```

No me funciona porque la funcion each se esta repitiendo, la consola me muestra que se llama 3 veces y es por ello que el botton no se bloquea o desbloquea correctamente.Espero puedan ayudarme

[image: Esto me muestra en consola]

Comment: La que se repite es la función each() me equivoque en el comentario de codigo

Comment: El bloqueo desbloqueo del botón está fuera de la función del bloque `each`, así que el `log` hace lo que tiene que hacer...